# Moving files from SD card to mounted USB drive using FTP client

Tags: usb, remote, mount, data-transfer

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple: move a file from my SD card to a mounted USB drive, using filezilla as FTP client

Here's what I get:
Status: Renaming  '/home/s0ubap/file.avi' to '/mnt/file.avi'
Command:    RNFR file.avi
Response:   350 Ready for RNTO.
Command:    RNTO /mnt/file.avi
Response:   550 Rename failed.

File: -rw-rw-rw- 1 debian-transmission debian-transmission
Destination folder: drwxrwxrwx 2 root root

Using manually 'mv' command in SSH works, while this very same command used by sftp does not.

Comment: I also tried sftp, which uses mv command. Didn't work...

Comment: Can you type "ls -l" and edit your question with the output, only the related file's line and also the folders containing it up to root would be enough.

Comment: Very confused. Are both the SD card and the mounted USB drive on the same pi? If so, why use an FTP client? Why not just ssh into the pi and move it from the command line?

Comment: Because I have several files to move/rename, and the ftp client (filezilla) allows me to drag and drop easily.

Comment: are you using the same user when move file via ssh and ftp? Sounds like permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the rep to comment, so i have to answer.

> Because I have several files to move/rename, and the ftp client (filezilla) allows me to drag and drop easily.

Why not use something like

```
mv /home/s0ubap/*.avi /mnt/.
```

to move all the needed (avi) files at once? You could also use find for filtering:

```
find <your_src_dir> -regex '<regex>' -exec mv '{}' <your_dest_dir>/. \;
```

In your case you'd have:

```
find /home/s0ubap -regex '.*\.avi' -exec mv '{}' /mnt/. \;
```

Depending on your use case, you may have to change the regex.

Comment: Sure, I already have python scripts to move some of my files. But I still need to manipulate some files manually.